# Google sheets API. Асинхронность. Телеграмм бот. Aiogram. Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, асинхронность, google-sheets-api

**Здравствуйте, посоветуйте как быть.**

В телеграмм боте написанном на Aiogram всплывает проблема. Когда один из пользователей как-то взаимодействует с таблицей, весь бот стопорится на 1-2 секунды, т.е другие пользователи не могут пользоваться остальным функционалом бота, даже с тем, который не связан с таблицами.

**Вопрос**
Как работать с асинхронностью?
Какой инструмент посоветуете?

Answer (score 0):

Все функции, которые отправляли запрос к таблице я засунул в новый поток с помощью библиотеки threading